# Alternative to System.DateTime.Now.Ticks in the .NET Micro Framework?

Tags: c#, micro-optimization, .net-micro-framework

I'm using `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` in a time-critical piece of code, and am finding it to be a bottleneck. This is almost certainly due to the overhead of instantiating a `DateTime` class that goes on behind the scenes.

I was told that I could get this information from `System.Environment.TickCount`. However, this is in milliseconds, which are too coarse a measurement for what I need. Although this was roughly twice as fast.

Is there some way to get the accuracy of `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` without the overhead of constructing `System.DateTime.Now`?

Comment: `DateTime` is a *struct*, so "instantiation" does not happen.

Comment: @Kirk: No, but year calculations do!

Comment: I haven't used it before, so I don't know if it'll fit your needs, but check out [Utility.GetMachineTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.utility.getmachinetime.aspx). I found it referenced on [this forum post](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/97-systemdiagnosticsstopwatch-class/).

Comment: @cbley: Tried it. I get pretty much the same time as before.

Comment: Sorry Eric. I don't think there is an alternative. The only other way I see would be to drop down to a lower level, like assembly language. If you are using an Intel processor, then there is a "Time Stamp Counter" and High Resolution Event Timer that will do what you need, but you need to access it through Assembler Language or C.

Comment: Just because DateTime has 100 ns resolution doesn't mean you actually get that kind of precision - ultimately, the real precision of DateTime.Now (at least on windows, don't know about micro framework) is more like 16 ms.

So if milliseconds are "too coarse for what you need", what do you need?

The bigger question is why you are getting the current timestamp (from whatever source in whatever format) in your innermost loop where it's becoming a bottleneck.

Comment: (response from when I posted the above in an answer deleted now) 20ths of milliseconds is what I'm after – Eric 2 mins ago

Comment: @Random: Looking for 20ths of milliseconds of accuracy. I guess I'll have a go at refactoring the code.

Comment: There is class available under System.Diagnostics Namespace called StopWatch. I read at multiple places that it is more accurate than Datime.Now.Ticks

Answer (score 4):

Many microcontrollers have a Real Time Clock which runs of a 32768 Hz crystal, which feeds a ripple timer or a pulse counter built into the hardware.

For instance, this document:
http://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/FEZ/Beginners%20guide%20to%20NETMF.pdf
on page 91 describes using a pulse counter on the USBIZI device.

It also links to this document
http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/philips/lpc23xx_um.pdf
which on p. 585 describes the TickCounterRegister
6.2.2 Clock Tick Counter Register (CTCR - 0xE002 4004)

So, you should be able to read that register to get a rolling count of 65536 ticks.  If your elapsed time is less than a .5 seconds between two reads of that register, a signed subtraction, and adding 65536 if less than 0 will give you the elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

Eric,

Just so you understand too, when you call the Ticks property of DateTime, what is happening is the .NET framework is converting the date and time (in milliseconds) to a Tick value. In other words, the Tick value you are getting back is not a measurement of time elapsed, but just a conversion of the date time structure, which itself is measured in milliseconds. You may feel like you are getting some high resolution timing by using Ticks, but in reality, milliseconds is as good as you are getting using DateTime anyway. The tick value divides the number of milliseconds elapsed by something like 0x2500 and that is why you are getting a high precision number. But keep in mind that time is still elapsing in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you need the time for. For example, if you are trying to compare two time instances from the same running instance of your application, then you can try using DateTime.UtcNow, which is not adjusted for locale or DST.

If you need to trigger an event at a specific time, use a Timer (probably System.Threading.Timer if you care that much about the granularity, although System.Timers.Timer is easier to use).

If you need it for some other reason, please specify.